# Space on html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is an easy question, but I cannot seem to solve it. My html table can be seen at the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rochefort/kvUKG/

And also included here:

```
 <table style="background:#fff;width:300px;margin-left:14px;" class="form"> 
    <tbody>
       <tr style=""> 
          <td class="bosluk"></td> 
          <td class="alis_baslik"><strong>ALIŞ</strong></td> 
          <td class="satis_baslik"><strong>SATIŞ</strong></td> 
       </tr> 
       <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #e4e4e4;"> 
          <td class="ikonlar"><strong>$ </strong></td> 
          <td class="kurlar">DOLAR</td> 
          <td class="alis">2.2804</td> 
          <td class="satis">2.2914</td> 
       </tr> 
       <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #e4e4e4;"> 
          <td class="ikonlar"><strong>$ </strong></td> 
          <td class="kurlar"><strong>DOLAR</strong></td> 
          <td class="alis">2.2804</td> 
          <td class="satis">2.2914</td> 
       </tr> 
       <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #e4e4e4;"> 
          <td class="ikonlar"><strong>$ </strong></td> 
          <td class="kurlar"><strong>DOLAR</strong></td> 
          <td class="alis">2.2804</td> 
          <td class="satis">2.2914</td> 
       </tr> 
       <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #e4e4e4;"> 
          <td class="ikonlar"><strong>$ </strong></td> 
          <td class="kurlar"><strong>DOLAR</strong></td> 
          <td class="alis">2.2804</td> 
          <td class="satis">2.2914</td> 
       </tr> 
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

I implemented CSS but the `DOLLAR` item has too much space. How can I remove this extra space?

Comment: You mean the `padding-right: 112px`? :/

Comment: I must agree with OhMrBigshot. Remove all those paddings on td elements and clean your code. Those blank spots you created by your own. If you have a vision how this should look at the end - upgrade your question by adding some image. Maybe this way should be easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text-align: right` with `padding-right` instead of `padding-left`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BfD2v/

```
.ikonlar {
    padding-right:5px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weigth: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-align: right;
}
```

If you want to make the whole column narrower, you can set the width od the column with this:

```
.bosluk, .ikonlar {
    width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also probably use `<th>` tags for the headers. The columns would align themselves under the `<td>` tags then. Like:

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <th>Month</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>January</td>
  <td>$100</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>February</td>
  <td>$80</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```